# Http Web request, difference when url does not exists and when url exists but issue when downloading

Tags: c#, httprequest, webclient, httpresponse

```
var url1 = "https://www.regulations.gov/contentStreamer?documentId=BIS-2018-0006-16235&attachmentNumber=2&contentType=pdf"; // url exist but issue when downloading
var url2 = "https://www.regulations.gov/contentStreamer?documentId=BIS-2018-0006-16010&attachmentNumber=2&contentType=pdf"; // url does not exist

try
{

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    response.Close();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // i am getting http 500 server error exception when trying to see if both urls exist.
}
```

Can anyone help me to figure out a better way to get response when url does not exist and when there is a issue downloading url.

Comment: Set a break point, try both cases, spot the difference.

Comment: I tried break point at ; HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; both return exception 500

Comment: If it helps, I get 500 from both of them to. The content of the 500 is different, so you could analyse that I guess.

Comment: @Davesoft you are right, content of 500 error is different. I cant seem to find in thrown exception that content. Do you have idea how would i get to that part?

Comment: The content definitely won't be in the exception. It should be in GetResponseStream()

Comment: It might be better to find out why you are getting a internal server error.

Comment: @Davesoft how do you get GetResponseStream() if code fails on WebRequest.Create(url) ???

Comment: @ivcubr any suggestions how could i do that???

Comment: @milo thank you for editing post and making it look cleaner. this is my first post so i am getting familiar...

Comment: @Marko I would say contact the site owner but its a .gov address. This appears to be an issue with the URL itself because searching for that document on their site results in the same broken URL. This URL will give you a valid response: `https://www.regulations.gov/contentStreamer?documentId=BIS-2018-0002-1811&attachmentNumber=2&contentType=pdf`

Comment: @ivcubr Thank you for your comment. I am working on small program that checks if url exists on gov website and if it does then try to download. The issue is that some of urls return same error as if file does not exist or there is issue when try to download. HTTP 500 internal server error.  My goal is to alert user when when there is an issue downloading and leave it alone when url does not exists

Comment: I've done this kind of thing with WebClient before, I don't know why webrequest fails creation though, it should create and have a 500 and a response object. Just because we pesky humans think 500 is bad, doesn't make it so :D

Comment: @Marko I would be at a loss for how to handle this because the webpage would not load so not sure how you would want to differientate it from another one that does not exist.